# Importing Xamarin Android project into Android Studio

Tags: android, xamarin

Is it possible to import my Xamarin Android project into Android Studio? If so, how can this be done? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need this? It's not possible, Xamarin uses completely different infrastructure and project structure.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Android studio doesn't support C# code. If you want your layout to be copied then you may do that with minor changes. The xml code is somewhat similar but not the backend code.

Comment: it is not possible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. The best you can do is import all of your `Resources` into an Android Studio solution. However you will need to change any layout resources from `.axml` to `.xml`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

While like others here have already stated it's not possible to directly import your Xamarin Android solution into Android Studio.

However, if you are just interested in working with Android studio's XML tooling. There is a nice Visual Studio Extension (so Windows only) call [XamarIDEA](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9f5a516a-f4d0-4228-9d25-d0273abebf33) ([Github](https://github.com/EgorBo/Xamaridea)) which allows for easy conversion of your AXML files to XML. Additionally, it create a temp Android Studio project with all your XML files syncing changes between Visual Studio and Android Studio automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done for the layout files just by changing the file type from `.axml` to `.xml` but converting the `.cs` files to `.java` is the biggest struggle. So, i would not suggest you to do so.

Also there could be some architectural differences, which might affect the code base as well.